# Create variables dynamically in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to generate release notes in an azure piplelines stage and push the note to an azure service bus.

How do I expose the variable in a bash script then consume it in a subsequent job in the same stage?

I'm using a bash task to execute a `git` command and trying to export it as an environment variable which I want to use in the following job.

```
  - stage: PubtoAzureServiceBus
    variables:
      COMMIT_MSG: "alsdkfgjdsfgjfd"
    jobs:
      - job: gitlog
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Write your commands here
                
                export COMMIT_MSG=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"Author: %aN%n%nCommit: %H%n%nNotes:%n%n%B")
                env | grep C
      - job:
        pool: server
        dependsOn: gitlog
        steps:
          - task: PublishToAzureServiceBus@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Slack Release Notifications'
              messageBody: |
                {
                  "channel":"XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "username":"bot",
                  "iconEmoji":"",
                  "text":":airhorn: release :airhorn: \n`$(COMMIT_MSG)`"
                }
              signPayload: false
              waitForCompletion: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [logging syntax and output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies) like it is shown here:

```yaml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true"
     # or on Windows:
     # - script: echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true
       name: printvar

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    condition: in(stageDependencies.A.A1.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Job B1
  - job: B2
    variables:
      varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['printvar.shouldrun'] ]
    steps:
    - script: echo $(varFromA) # this step uses the mapped-in variable
```

Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage) to check documentation.

So you need to replace

```
                export COMMIT_MSG=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"Author: %aN%n%nCommit: %H%n%nNotes:%n%n%B")
```

wit logging command with `isOutput=true`

and then map it as here

```yaml
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - bash: |
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true"
    name: ProduceVar  # because we're going to depend on it, we need to name the step
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    # map the output variable from A into this job
    varFromA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['printvar.shouldrun']
  steps:
  - script: echo $(varFromA) # this step uses the mapped-in variable
```

as you want to share variable between jobs (not stages as it shown in the first example).

Comment: is the output generated by the echo command in job A1 and saved in a variable called printvar?

Comment: Yes. But important is to have `isOutput=true`

Comment: where do I run the git log command? is that appended to  echo "##vso..."

Comment: Before, and assign result to variable. and then use it here `##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]<put variable here>`